# Unable to bind kendo datagrid datasource to Azure Mobile Services?

Tags: kendo-ui, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to bind kendo UI datagrid to my azure backend mobile services table (SASA) following this tutorial.
http://ignaciofuentes.com/archive/2014/01/20/zumo-kendo/
but unfortunately for some reasons it is not working. I have tried updating the mobile services javascript sdk from 1.0.0 to 1.1.5 still with no luck.

Here is my code.. can anyone point out what am I doing wrong.. the service is returning proper JSON..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/everlive">
<style>html { font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.528/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

```
     <div id="example">
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("MY SERVICE URL", "MY API KEY");
var table = client.getTable("sasa");
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: {
    read: function (options) {
        table.includeTotalCount() //necessary for grid to paginate
             .read()
             .done(options.success);
    },
    update: function (options) {
        table.update(options.data)
             .done(options.success);
    },
    create: function (options) {
        var item = options.data;
        delete item.id; //ZUMO doesnt allow you to set your own ID. It gets auto generated.
        table.insert(item)
             .done(options.success);
    },
    destroy: function (options) {
        table.del(options.data)
             .done(options.success);
    }
},
pageSize: 10,
schema: {
    total: "totalCount",
    model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: {
            id: { type: "number" },
            name: { type: "string" },
            developer: { type: "string" },
        }
    }
}});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
pageable: true,
dataSource: dataSource,
columns: [
    "name",
    "developer", {
    command: [{
        name: "edit",
        text: "Edit"
    }, {
        name: "destroy",
        text: "Delete"
    }]
}],
toolbar: [{
    name: "create"
}],
editable: "inline"
});      


       });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On a test I did a while back using a kendo datasource and a windows azure mobile service, my dataSource CRUD methods were a bit different.

```
create: function(options) {
    delete options.data.id;
    client.getTable("Customer").insert(options.data).done(function(data) {
      options.success(data);
    });
  },
  read: function(options) {
    client.getTable("Customer").read().done(function(data) {
      options.success(data);
    });
  },
  update: function(options) {
    client.getTable("Customer").update(options.data).done(function(data) {
      options.success(data);
    });
  },
  destroy: function(options) {
    client.getTable("Customer").del(options.data).done(function(data) {
      options.success(data);
    });
  }
```

And it worked properly.  Perhaps try changing the `.done(options.success);` to

```
.done(function(data) { 
    options.success(data);
});
```

And see if it works ?

--edit I rebuilt my MobileService I used to test with and dug up the code, it still works properly.  Here is the sample at jsbin  http://jsbin.com/jirexo/2/edit